# Is downloading Ubuntu via the windows installer a better alternative to using Ubuntu within a virtual box?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, virtualbox

I will soon be starting an application support job and when I asked my soon-to-be line manager, "what should I get to grips with before I start?", He specifically stated that I should learn "the principles and some general knowledge of Linux/Ubuntu". I believe that the best way to do this is to start using Ubuntu and follow online tutorials.

I am currently running windows 7 and was about to install ubuntu through a virtual box. While experiencing some problems with the install I came across the windows installer. I am  a total beginner when it comes to Ubuntu but considering how much easier it seems to be to use the windows installer, is it really a better alternative to using virtual box (or something similar)?

Thanks

Comment: It probably is, if you need Ubuntu running on real hardware. If not, VirtualBox will do, and you won't have to reboot.

Answer (score 3):

(Not only) for the purpose of "getting your feet wet" using a virtual machine is perfectly fine. Additional benefit: you can use snapshots to undo things you tried. I definitely recommend that approach.